# Powershell: TextBlock in Runspace – Add Inline with fontstyles

Tags: powershell, textblock, runspace

I have a problem with powershell and styling a part of Text in a *TextBlock*.

I use a function to push text to a runspace window and a *TextBlock* in it, which works fine.

```
Function Update-Log {
    Param (
        $Content,
        $type = "Black"
    )
    $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
        [action]{$syncHash.log_txt.Foreground = $type; $syncHash.log_txt.Inlines.Add($Content); },
        "Normal"
    )
}
```

Even the change of color works without problems. But now I would like to mark individual words **bold**. I have tried a pragmatic approach:

```
Update-Log "Here is some <bold>bold</bold> text."
```

Unfortunately this did not work. Can you help me to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
   $syncHash.TextBlockName.Dispatcher.invoke(
        [action]{ 
            $Run = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.Run
            $Run.Text = $Content
            $Run.FontWeight = $weight
            $Run.TextDecorations = $decorations
            $Run.FontStyle = $atyle
            $syncHash.TextBlockName.Inlines.Add($Run)
            },
        "Normal"
    )
}
```

Comment: This is one fine solution that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize bold:

```
Update-Log "Here is some <Bold>bold</Bold> text."
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help :/